# Issue with the Calendar Lists

Tags: java, list, exception, calendar

so, a little backstory: Before we start, i need to make adjustments only on Schedule class, everything else is already given and is just for understanding the problem.

**Requirement:**
You must implement a **Scheduler** class that contains a single method, **schedule()**. The method receives as a parameter a list of objects of type **Meeting**, previously implemented(will post it aswell), and modifies the list so that it contains only the meetings that can be scheduled in a single meeting room, so that they do not overlap, sorted ascending according to Starting date. The solution found must contain a maximum number of meetings.

If there are several solutions with a maximum number of meetings, find the solution that has the smallest lexicographic string of meeting end dates. In case of equality between the end dates, the meeting with the lowest start date is required.

Two meetings with start dates in ascending order overlap if the start date of the second is less than or equal to the end date of the first.

**Your code should only contain the definition of the Scheduler class and any helper classes.**

Method signature:
public static void schedule(List >Meeting< meetings) // reversed to be able to write

Careful

You no longer need to implement the Meeting class, it will be automatically included in the code you send and will be defined as follows:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

class Meeting implements Comparable<Meeting> {
    private Calendar starting, ending;

    public Meeting(Calendar starting, Calendar ending) {
        if (starting.compareTo(ending) > 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Data");
        }
        this.starting = starting;
        this.ending = ending;
    }

    public Calendar getStarting() {
        return starting;
    }

    public Calendar getEnding() {
        return ending;
    }

    public int compareTo(Meeting m) {
        return this.starting.compareTo(m.getStarting());
    }

    public String toString() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        return sdf.format(starting.getTime()) + " -> " + sdf.format(ending.getTime());
    }
}
 class Scheduler{
public static void schedule(List<Meeting> meetings) {
    Collections.sort(meetings, new Comparator<Meeting>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Meeting a, Meeting b) {
            if (a.getStarting().equals(b.getStarting())) {
                return a.getEnding().compareTo(b.getEnding());
            } else {
                return a.getStarting().compareTo(b.getStarting());
            }
        }
    });

    for (int i = 1; i < meetings.size(); ++i) {
        Meeting a = meetings.get(i);
        Meeting b = meetings.get(i - 1);

        if (a.getStarting().get(Calendar.YEAR) == b.getEnding().get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            if (a.getStarting().get(Calendar.MONTH) == b.getEnding().get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
                if (a.getStarting().get(Calendar.DATE) < b.getEnding().get(Calendar.DATE)) {
                    meetings.remove(a);
                }
            } else if (a.getStarting().get(Calendar.MONTH) < b.getEnding().get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
                meetings.remove(a);
            }
        } else if (a.getStarting().get(Calendar.YEAR) < b.getEnding().get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            meetings.remove(a);
        }
    }
}
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            List<Meeting> l = new ArrayList<>();
            l.add(new Meeting(new GregorianCalendar(1, 2, 3),
                    new GregorianCalendar(2, 2, 3)));
            l.add(new Meeting(new GregorianCalendar(1, 2, 3),
                    new GregorianCalendar(5, 2, 3)));
            l.add(new Meeting(new GregorianCalendar(3, 2, 3),
                    new GregorianCalendar(5, 2, 3)));
            Scheduler.schedule(l);
            System.out.println(l);  // [03/03/0001 12:00:00 -> 03/03/0002 12:00:00, 03/03/0003 12:00:00 -> 03/03/0005 12:00:00]  this is a test from platform, if we run the code with the added information, we are supposed to have this on output.
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, the code seems to be working fine but if i make another test like:

Test 1:

```
l.add(new Meeting(new GregorianCalendar(5, 2, 3),
new GregorianCalendar(5, 2, 3)));
l.add(new Meeting(new GregorianCalendar(6, 2, 3),
new GregorianCalendar(7, 2, 3)));
l.add(new Meeting(new GregorianCalendar(4, 2, 3),
new GregorianCalendar(5, 2, 3)));
l.add(new Meeting(new GregorianCalendar(6, 2, 7),
new GregorianCalendar(6, 2, 7)));
    The output is this " [03/03/0004 12:00:00 -> 03/03/0005 12:00:00, 03/03/0005 12:00:00 -> 03/03/0005 12:00:00, 03/03/0006 12:00:00 -> 03/03/0007 12:00:00] "
     instead of this
 "[03/03/0004 12:00:00 -> 03/03/0005 12:00:00, 07/03/0006 12:00:00 -> 07/03/0006 12:00:00]
```

I am really trying so hard to see where is the issue but i can't find it, if anyone sees something please text me, i've spent so much time on trying to find the issue but i simply cannot, thank you!

So again, the adjustments have to be made only in the Scheduler class.

On demand, i can give another example, but it s too much written so far, give me a comment if you need another example of why it isnt working.

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the advice, do you have any ideea how i can make this work in other way?

Comment: I have posted multiple times on the topic. Search for the term “appointment”. In short: You’ll need to store a `LocalDateTime` *and* a `ZoneId`, storing both while keeping them separate. To calculate a moment for scheduling, combine the two to make a `ZonedDateTime`, but do not store. And store a `Duration` rather than an ending time.

Comment: In real work, I would add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library for use in detecting overlap of appointments with its `Interval` class. But if you are doing schoolwork, perhaps you are supposed to do the logic yourself.

Comment: Im solving it for a platform and this is how it is meant to be solved, i have to use only these stuff

Comment: If anyone can help me adjust my code to make it work would really appreciate it, i still need help